# @Parameter(required = false) not working in swagger open api v3

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, swagger-ui, springdoc-openapi-ui

my project is java spring boot 2 with maven . I use springdoc-openapi-ui dependency. problem is
@Parameter(required = false) not working on my api params.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the Swagger-specific `@ApiParam` annotation in addition to the Spring annotations?

Comment: `@Parameter` isn't a spring annotation, so not sure how that should be handled. You should be using `@RequestParam` which is a Spring MVC annotation.

Comment: thank you . my problem is with annotation @Parameter that belongs to io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameter. by default should be required = false, but as in swagger-ui screen shot shows, labeled with * required!

Comment: dear @user991710.@ApiParam belongs to springfox-swagger , i use springdoc-openapi-ui.

Comment: thanks m-deinum  problem resolved by add @RequestParam.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't know how much of swagger annotations Springdoc-openapi supports but according to its own example at [PetApiDemo](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-demos/blob/master/springdoc-openapi-spring-boot-2-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springdoc/demo/app2/api/PetApi.java) in */findByStatus* or */findByTags* endpoints you can see by applying `@RequestParam(required = false)` which is a Spring Annotation! a parameter has become optional.

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
default ResponseEntity<List<Pet>> findPetsByStatus(
        @Parameter(
                explode = Explode.TRUE, 
                name = "status", 
                in = ParameterIn.QUERY, 
                description = "Status values that need to be considered for filter", 
                style = ParameterStyle.FORM, 
                schema = @Schema(
                        type = "string", defaultValue = "available", 
                        allowableValues = {"available", "pending", "sold"}
                )
        )
        @Valid @RequestParam(value = "status", required = false)
        List<String> status) {
    return getDelegate().findPetsByStatus(status);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I analyzed the options reported above and came to the following conclusions

Both `@RequestParam(required = false)` and `@Nullable` result in the same behavior in the swagger documentation by removing the ***required**, however the behavior is different in the application:

- Using `@RequestParam(required = false)` makes the method more descriptive but if the object is not passed it will be null.
  This requires handling to avoid NullpointerException
- When using `@Nullable`, if the object is not passed, an instance of the object is still received with all attributes as null, in this case not requiring treatment

In my case I chose to use `@Nullable` in the interface to keep the default behavior

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. My solution is add jakarta.annotation.@Nullable for non required parameters.

```
public ResponseEntity<?> getAllByMonthAndYear(
        @Nullable @RequestParam("month") Integer month,
        @Nullable @RequestParam("year") Integer year
) {...
```